# How to use AWS Data pipeline shellcommandprecondition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

My first question here! I've built a Data Pipeline for daily ETL whichs moves and tranforms data between Aurora, Redshift and Hive. All works well however I'm truly stuck on trying to implement a **Shellcommandprecondition**. The aim is to check the total row count in a view sitting on Aurora MySQL. If the view is empty (0 rows) then Data Pipeline should execute. If there are rows in the view - then the pipeline wait a bit, and then eventually fail after 4 retries.

Can someone help me out with the code for the actual check and query? This is what I've got so far but no luck with it:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=`mysql -u USER -pPW -h MASTERPUBLIC -p 3306 -D DBNAME -s -N -e "SELECT count(*) from MyView"`
if $count = 0 
then exit 0 
else exit 1
fi
```

In the pipeline definition it looks as follows:

```
 {
      "retryDelay": "15 Minutes",
      "scriptUri": "s3://mybucket/ETLprecondition.bash",
      "maximumRetries": "4",
      "name": "CheckViewEmpty",
      "id": "PreconditionId_pznm2",
      "type": "ShellCommandPrecondition"
    },
```

I have very little experience coding so I may be completely off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, a few hours have passed and I finally solved it. There were a few issues holding me up.

1. Mysql client was not installed on the ec2 instance. Solved that by adding install command
2. Next issue was that the if $count = 0 line wasn't working as I would have expected it to do with my limited experience. Exchanged it for if [ "$count" -eq "0" ];

Final and working code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
if type mysql >/dev/null 2>&1; then
count=`mysql -u USER -pPW -h MASTERPUBLIC -p 3306 -D DBNAME -s -N -e "SELECT count(*) from MyView"`
if [ "$count" -eq "0" ];
then exit 0
else exit 1
fi
else
sudo yum install -y mysql
count=`mysql -u USER -pPW -h MASTERPUBLIC -p 3306 -D DBNAME -s -N -e "SELECT count(*) from MyView"`
if [ "$count" -eq "0" ];
then exit 0
else exit 1
fi
fi
```